# Android Studio: Add as Library option missing

Tags: android, android-studio

I've started using Android Studio and have encountered a problem. I don't seem to figure out why I can't see the **Add as Library** option when I add a library in my project.
The steps I performed in order to add library:
 * Add library in the **libs** folder present in the **app** repository.
 * Right-click to see for option **Add as Library**. (Cannot see it!)
 * Since the above step didn't work I thought of adding the library directly in the libs folder i.e. in the Explorer. FAILED!

Because of this I'm unable to proceed with my project.

P.S.: I've removed Eclipse and I don't wanna install do the setup all over again.

**build.gradle**file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
          compileSdkVersion 21
          buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

          defaultConfig {
                         applicationId "com.example.team1cloud.cloudapp"
                         minSdkVersion 15
                         targetSdkVersion 21
                         versionCode 1
                         versionName "1.0"
                        }
buildTypes {
    release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
          }
        }
dependencies
      {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
       compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev161-1.19.1'
       compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-api-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-api-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-api-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-api-client-java6-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-api-client-protobuf-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-api-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-api-client-xml-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-http-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-java6-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-jetty-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc.jar')
       compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
       compile files('libs/gson-2.1.jar')
       compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
       compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
       compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
       compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar')
       compile files('libs/jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar')
       compile files('libs/jetty-6.1.26.jar')
       compile files('libs/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar')
       compile files('C:/Users/sjeet/AndroidStudioProjects/CloudApp/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
     }
```

Thanks. **Please help!!!**

Comment: post your gradle file

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio is gradle based. If you have a jar file as dependency for your project, open the `build.gradle` file and add in the dependency's section

```
 compile files('libs/name_file.jar')
```

if you imported the source code of the library as dependency you can use

```
compile project(':NameProject')
```

to compile it.

You should be able to do the same thing trough the UI.

Right click on your project and click on `Open Module Settings`, and then click on the `Dependencies` tab. From there you can add jar or library project as dependency for your main project

Comment: I'm creating a project using GoogleDrive API. I added GoogleApIClient library and also added this:  
        compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
in the build.gradle. It wouldn't work.

Comment: did you sync it again ?

Comment: How do I understand if the library **google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar** is a library, file or modular dependency?

Yes, I've been trying since the last 3 hours!

Answer (score 0):

I wasted another day following all of the above suggestions with no success. Then what I did was...

1. closed my project
2. closed Android Studio
3. used Windows 10 to simply copy a jar file from another location directly into the `MyProject/app/libs` folder
4. started Android Studio, opened my project waited for sync to finish, ensured that it was in Project view not in Android view
5. The jar file showed up in the libs folder
   and, like magic,
6. "Add as Library" appeared near the bottom of list when I right-clicked the jar file. Clicked it, living happily ever after :)
   QED